# Thermochemistry questions regarding enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

I have a few questions about *heat of combustion*. I have two different scenarios that I was to present:

**Scenario 1:** Given heat of combustion in the equation

$\ce{CH4 + 2O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$ and $\Delta H =\pu{-889kJ mol-1}$

Q1: Would $1$ mol methane produce $\pu{889 kJ}$; whereas, $1$ mol of oxygen would produce $\pu{444.5 kJ}$?

**Scenario 2:** Given the energy produced per mol of a molecular compound

$\ce{C2H6O + 3O2 -> 2CO2 + 3H2O}$ and $\Delta H=?$

However, we are given that the oxygen produces $\pu{400 kJ}$ of energy.

Q2: Would that mean that the $\Delta H=3 \times400=\pu{1200 kJ mol-1}$?

It would be really great if someone could explain the theories behind thermochemistry.

Comment: What do you mean by theories behind thermochemistry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not separate the species on the left and assign enthalpy variations to each of them. On Scenario 1, you say that 1 mol of methane reacts with 2 mols of oxygen, and the variation of enthalpy for this is −889 kJ (since it is 1 mol of methane). If you had 2 mols of methane, and 4 mols of oxygen, $\Delta$H would be 2*(-889) kJ, and so on. As you mentioned, if only 1 mol of oxygen were available, only 0.5 mol of methane would react and $\Delta$H would be 0.5*(-889) kJ

So, for Scenario 2, you said it was given that

> the oxygen produces 400kJ of energy

This probably means that, for each mol of oxygen that reacts with ethanol, 400 kJ of energy is released. So yes, if you wanted the $\Delta$H for the reaction, you should multiply by 3 and get that $\Delta$H = -1200 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>.
This is in agreement with the measured molar enthalpy of combustion of ethanol (-1211 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>)

Comment: Thank you @Rafael L ! Appreciate the explanation!